# My code is lying to me

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a code that checks if a word has multiple of the same letters in it, so I split each letter into an array and wrote this code. the "correctGuesses" variable is supposed to be the number of duplicate letters. The Array contains the strings ("H, E, L, L ,O").

```
Dim newCharArray() As Char = wordArray(rndNumber).ToCharArray
ReDim Preserve charToString_2(newCharArray.Length - 1)
Dim cBoolean As Boolean = False

For i As Integer = 0 To (newCharArray.Length - 1) Step 1

    charToString_2(i) = newCharArray(i)
    MsgBox(charToString_2(i))

Next



For j As Integer = 0 To (charToString_2.Length - 1) Step 1
    For b As Integer = 0 To (charToString_2.Length - 1) Step 1

        MsgBox("Is " & charToString_2(j) & " = " & charToString_2(b) & "?")

        If j = b Then

            MsgBox(j & " is equal to " & b & ", continuing.")
            Exit For

        End If
        If CStr(charToString_2(b)) = CStr(charToString_2(b)) Then

            MsgBox("Yes, +1")
            correctGuesses += 1
            charToString_2(b) = "Replaced"
            cBoolean = True

        End If

        MsgBox("No, Continuing.")

    Next                    
Next
```

The first if statement works, so whenever j = b, it exits and proceeds. But then the next loop, it checks if "E" is equal to "H", and it returns true! I have no idea why!

Comment: You have b as the argument on both sides.

Comment: Damn it's always something as obvious as that, I'm ashamed.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Why not just post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is almost there. You can tweak it a little.

```
Dim stringtoCheck As String = wordArray(rndNumber)

For j As Integer = 0 To (stringtoCheck.Length - 2)
    For b As Integer = j+1 To (stringtoCheck.Length - 1)

        If stringtoCheck.chars(b) = stringtoCheck.chars(j) Then

            correctGuesses += 1
            cBoolean = True

        End If

    Next                    
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides counts for the different characters in a string.  Casing is shown.

```
    Dim wordToCheck As String = "heLlo racecar" 'note L and l
    Dim lettercounts As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
    For Each c As Char In wordToCheck ' .ToUpperInvariant '.ToLowerInvariant
        If Not lettercounts.ContainsKey(c) Then
            Dim ct As Integer = wordToCheck.Count(Function(ch) ch = c)
            lettercounts.Add(c, ct)
        End If
    Next

    'show the counts
    For Each ltrct As KeyValuePair(Of Char, Integer) In lettercounts
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}  {1}", ltrct.Key, ltrct.Value))
    Next
```